# Stopwatch not working with 24 hours intervals but worked with a shorter periods like minutes

Tags: .net, vb.net, setinterval, stopwatch

Stopwatch not working with 24 hours intervals but worked with a shorter periods like minutes

```
Dim s1 As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
        s1.Start()
        'Dim starttime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        While s1.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        End While
```

the same code works correctly
when use this method
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1440)
instead of
TimeSpan.FromHours(24)

Comment: Firstly, that is horrendous code. That is what is known as a "busy wait loop" and it is one of the most despicable code constructs possible. NEVER use a loop that does nothing to wait for a particular state. If at all possible, rely on events. In this case, you if you wanted to wait 24 hours then you could just start a `Timer` with the `Interval` set to 24 hours. That would not be completely precise but very close. If you needed it closer, use an `Interval` of almost 24 hours and then change it to 1 second after the first `Tick`.

Comment: If you really did need to use a loop then you should at least have a sleep/delay inside it so that you're not using 100% of your CPU the whole time.

Comment: As for the issue, it has nothing to do with the `Stopwatch` as reported. Whether you use `TimeSpan.FromHours` or `TimeSpan.FromMinutes`, you're still producing a `TimeSpan` and that is what you're comparing the `Stopwatch.Elapsed` to. A `TimeSpan` is a `TimeSpan`, regardless of how it was created. For the comparison to work in one case and not the other, those two `TimeSpan` methods would have to be producing different results. Unless your system is broken, they aren't. The issue is something else. Are you really testing by maxing out your CPU for a whole day? NOT GOOD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments of jmcilhinney.

```
    Dim s1 As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
    s1.Start()
    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24.0#)
    Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(24.0# * 60.0#)
    Stop 'look at ts1 and ts2.  are they the same?
    'While s1.Elapsed < ts2
    While s1.Elapsed < ts1
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    End While
```

**Having shown this, his first comment should be heeded.**